# Cannot run nvidia driver and overheating after installing drivers

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I tried to do download several nvidia drviers via

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460
```

450 and 390. None of them worked for my gtx 760m, as when I run nvidia-smi, I constantly get the error.

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Also, after some installations my computer started to overheat. Why do you think my computer is overheating? Also, how can i download the correct nvidia driver for my graphics card. I disabled the secure boot but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The `gtx 760m` is not supported by either `450` or `460` Nvidia drivers.

If you are using Ubuntu 18.04, you can install the `418` driver.

Run

```
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia.*'
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-418
```

and reboot.

Your system may be overheating because an Nvidia driver was not properly installed.

Comment: That is surprising. I'm running a GTX 760 with nvidia-460 (+cuda +nvenc) without any problems... (on Manjaro , but that should work on Ubuntu too)